# JavaScript For Loop with Array with words

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to push the last 2 words from the first to the second array in a loop.

What am I doing wrong????

```js
var xMen = ["Professor X", "Cyclops", "Beast", "Iron-Man", "Hobgoblin"];
var freelancers = ["Legion", "Magneto"];

for (var i = 0; i < freelancers.length; i++) {
  if (i < 2) {
    freelancers.push(xMen.pop());
    console.log(freelancers);
  }
}
```

Comment: check .concat() method for arrays: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Comment: so you could: xMen.concat(freelancers.slice(freelancers.length - 3, freelancers.length - 1)

Comment: It is pushing elments in the second array. What are you expecting in the right order as in first array

Comment: so i needed to push the last 2 words from the first array!
I solved anyway! 
Ty for the help guys!!! And ty for the tips and not for the anwser itself